# Vue mixin's data appear in two places, this.$data.myMixinValue, and this.myMixinValue, is that normal?

Tags: vue.js

Why Vue mixin's data appear in two places, `this.$data.myMixinValue`, and `this.myMixinValue`, is that normal?

Please see this minimul example.

---

This is a mixin that tracks a mouse position

```js
const mousePagePositionMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      mousePagePosition: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.update);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.update);
  },
  methods: {
    update(event) {
      this.mousePagePosition.x = event.pageX;
      this.mousePagePosition.y = event.pageY;
    }
  }
};
```

And the Vue instance is simply

```js
export default {
  mixins: [mousePagePositionMixin],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$data.mousePagePosition); // has data
    console.log(this.mousePagePosition); // also has data
  }
};
```

You can see we got `mousePagePosition` appear in two different places, that's so weird, where should I actually consume these values?

Is it a bug?

---

The above code's code sandbox example.

[image: Edit mutable-meadow-p8n2i]

Comment: Yes. The `$data` is an internal store :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'a a feature.

[According to Vue document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)

```
vm.$data is a object.The data object that the Vue instance is observing. The Vue instance proxies access to the properties on its data object.
```